# Mismatched Type while returning generic Struct

Tags: rust

I am trying to create Connection Pool, using r2d2 postgres crate, and hold it in struct DBPool so that I can pass around this instance to different handlers for dbConn, but getting mismatch error during compilation. Unable to figure out the reason for this mismatch as PostgresConnectionManager implements ManageConnection trait so what is missing here.

Thanks in advance.

```
extern crate r2d2;
extern crate r2d2_postgres;

 use std::thread;
 use r2d2:: {Pool, ManageConnection};
 use r2d2_postgres::{TlsMode, PostgresConnectionManager};

fn main() {

    let pool = DBPool::<PostgresConnectionManager>::new();
    println!("{:?}", pool.pool);
}

struct DBPool <M: ManageConnection>{
    pool: Pool<M>
}

impl<M: ManageConnection> DBPool<M> {
    fn new()-> DBPool<M>  {
        let config = r2d2::Config::default();
        let manager = PostgresConnectionManager::new("postgresql://root@localhost:26257/db?sslmode=disable", TlsMode::None).unwrap();
        let p =  r2d2::Pool::new(config, manager).unwrap() ;

        println!("Pool p: {:?}", p);
        DBPool { pool: p}
    }
}
```

Compilation error:

```
 dbcon git:(master) ✗ cargo run
   Compiling dbcon v0.1.0 (file:///Users/arvindbir/projects/rust/dbcon)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:42:9
   |
42 |         DBPool { pool: p}
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found struct `r2d2_postgres::PostgresConnectionManager`
   |
   = note: expected type `DBPool<M>`
              found type `DBPool<r2d2_postgres::PostgresConnectionManager>`

error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `dbcon`.
```

Comment: This has been asked many times — I found 3 exact duplicates by just searching for the error message. Please **search for your question** before asking it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that 1 mismatch to 2:

```
fn new()-> DBPool<M>/*1*/  {
    let manager = PostgresConnectionManager::new
    let p =  r2d2::Pool::new(config, manager).unwrap() ;
    DBPool { pool: p}/*2*/
}
```

In `1` you tell I return any `DBPool<M>` where `M` any type that implement
`ManageConnection`, but then at `2` you tell I change my mind I return specific `M` = `PostgresConnectionManager`,
for example such signature allow you to write:

```
let d = DBPoll::<SqliteConnectionManager>::new();
```

so `rustc` report syntax error, to fix this issue you should specify
exact type:

```
fn new() -> DBPool<PostgresConnectionManager> {
```

Comment: Please **do not answer duplicates**. Instead, search before answering and then mark them as such.

Comment: Since this question is closed I can't answer, however for anyone stumbling across this post from Google, here's the real answer (the answer provided here doesn't work for the current version, since `PostgresConnectionManager` has a type parameter now): https://github.com/djc/bb8/issues/57#issuecomment-613304110